# How to cure dry voice from whisky? Water not working

Tags: vocal-range

I drink whisky with a high percent of alcohol (45%) to deepen my voice but today it just dried out my voice & my voice is stuck in a female range. What's the quickest way to moisturize my throat?

I drank a whole bottle 500mL of water & my voice is still creaky.

Comment: What gender are you? (For comparison, I'm a female who can sing a low C.)

Comment: Don't.  Just. Plain. Don't.  You will destroy your vocal cords in short order.   Take lessons and learn proper breath control.

Comment: Also,  how old are you, and why do you think it'd be horrible to be a tenor?

Comment: 24 male & I'd classify my voice as contralto right now. :-(

Answer (score 11):

> I drink whisky with a high percent of alcohol (45%) to deepen my voice but today it just dried out my voice & my voice is stuck in a female range. What's the quickest way to moisturize my throat?
>
> I drank a whole bottle 500mL of water & my voice is still creaky.

I think you should get off the expectation that your voice, a complex and intricate part of your body, is a viable target for that kind of sledgehammer quickfix in either direction.

Keeping hydrated is a good longterm strategy for keeping your voice in working order.  But it's not like you can undo prolonged intentional damage at the drop of a hat in that manner.

This sounds like "smoking a lot for a deeper voice gave me lung cancer.  Which mountain's air should I best breathe now to fix it?  I tried Mt Fuji but it didn't help and I spent more than an hour there."

Maybe you should be seeing a physician rather than StackExchange?

Comment: I only tried 1 sip of whisky daily for a week. The one sip deepened my voice according to a voice pitch app so far, but today the throat feels dry & squeaky.  I never thought this was a way to deepen voice in the longterm but for now I can't afford voice training but my feminine voice irks me.

Comment: You've now complained twice about having a "feminine" voice.  I think you may need some counseling about gender identification far more than music issues.  Vocal range has next to nothing to do with gender.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Cause my voice is so feminine I get misgendered all the time on the phone & girls don't find it attractive. What kind of vocal coach can help me learn to deepen?